# on the basis of one condition try to pick data from another field and then pull the data on the basis of second value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where date, transaction id, amount is available. "transaction id"s are numeric and alpha-numeric. First I need to check the first case where "transaction id" starts with a particular letter and then I need to pull the "date" for that particular "transaction id". Then according to that particular "date" I need to pull transaction data. Please help me how to do this.

Comment: Not anything actually. I am a beginner.

Comment: how about you post some actual data... its going to be hard to help without understanding what the data is.

Comment: transaction_id date amount
N01090057 30/10/2014 $3.72
N01090057 30/09/2014 $0.13
N010900576 30/09/2014 $458.86
1692870532 30/09/2014 $5.37
1692870531 30/09/2014 $22.26
1692870534 31/08/2014 $13.54
N010900571 31/08/2014 $5.55
N010900572 31/08/2014 $3.84
N010900573 31/08/2014 $18.35
N010900574 31/08/2014 $422.16
N010900575 31/08/2014 $0.13
169287105 7/08/2014 $15.28
169287053 7/08/2014 $15.28
169287105 7/08/2014 $0.15
169287106 7/08/2014 $4.34
169287107 7/07/2014 $67.72
169287109 7/06/2014 $290.12
169287101 7/08/2014 $6.26
N010900578 7/06/2014 $0.15

Comment: @avinandanghosh thank you for that. I have posted a working solution in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use an EXISTS clause to check for the date in a subquery like so.

This will return all transactions that occurred on a date that had a transaction_id starting with the letter N

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table st
WHERE EXISTS
(   SELECT 1 
    FROM some_table st1
    WHERE st1.date = st.date
      AND st1.transaction_id LIKE 'N%'
)
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/412d7/1)

these can also use an index on transaction_id which can speed things up

Comment: its saying "LEFT" invalid identifier. I have given a sample date.

Comment: @avinandanghosh is this MySQL? LEFT is a valid function in MySQL. if not then just change to LIKE... look at the fiddle links i posted

Comment: first I need to make a find the date where first time 'N' occurs and then need to pull all the data after that date irrespective of transaction_id

Comment: @avinandanghosh I had both methods I removed the other one just so its by date irrespective of transaction_id... I also put in LIKE instead of LEFT since it seems you are using something other than MySQL. look at the demo that is there. it has your data.

Comment: @avinandanghosh ok well then what I have up there is a working solution. if you want to try it out.. also here is that demo **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/412d7/1**

Comment: @avinandanghosh did this solve your issue? if so could you please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark under the votes for the answer) it would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find date(s) for transactionId, that starts with; lets say 'A':

```
SELECT date FROM your_table WHERE transactionId LIKE 'A%';
```

Now you may have multiple records as you are searching with `'LIKE'`, then according to the date(s) you can fetch data from your table as:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE date = '2014-12-25 10:40:00';
```

But if you know your transactionId accurately, then following query will be sufficient.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE transactionId = 'A1001';
```